# Calling functions with get() doesn't work in new Versions of Kendo

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

So the problem is that we have a kendo version of 2021
that everywhere in our project we used to call functions like this

```
viewModel.get("someFunction()");
```

and it worked fine but now that we are testing the latest Versions , it only works like this

```
viewModel.someFunction();
```

Does anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: Try without the brackets, e.g. viewModel.get("someFunction")...I use MVVM/observable all over the place and I have never used the brackets, just the field name like any other simple field.  It's possible that they broke your usage...I've noticed they have broken a lot of functionality that has worked since v1 a decade ago in the last 2 years.

Comment: thank you for your comment i will try it,why you dont use viewModel.someFunction(); ?

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/observableobject#important-notes, basically you should use get/set so that their internal dependency/notification stuff works properly so why not use it for all the fields for consistency.  Perhaps you are not supposed to use get with a method member and only simple members which is why they "fixed" it(which broke it for you...and possibly me and I just haven't found it yet).

Comment: there is a change that i found on the latest update in ghub and they add this exprToArray: function (expression, safe) {
                expression = expression || "";
                var FIELD_REGEX = /\[(?:(\d+)|['"](.*?)['"])\]|((?:(?!\[.*?\]|\.).)+)/g;
                var fields = [];

                expression.replace(FIELD_REGEX, function (_, index, indexAccessor, field) {
                    fields.push(kendo.isPresent(index) ? index : (indexAccessor || field));
                    return undefined$1;
                });

                return fields;
            },

Comment: getter: function(expression, safe) {
                var key = expression + safe;

                return getterCache[key] = getterCache[key] || (function (obj) {
                    var fields = kendo.exprToArray(expression, safe);

                    var result = obj;
                    for (var idx = 0; idx < fields.length; idx++) {
                        result = result[fields[idx]];
                        if (!kendo.isPresent(result) && safe) {
                            return result;
                        }
              }

           return result;
       }); },

Comment: dont know yet if this is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a change that i found on the latest update in ghub and they add this in

**Kendo UI R1 2023 (version 2023.1.117)**

```
 exprToArray: function (expression, safe) { expression = expression || ""; var FIELD_REGEX = /[(?:(\d+)|['"](.*?)['"])]|((?:(?![.*?]|\.).)+)/g; var fields = []; expression.replace(FIELD_REGEX, function (_, index, indexAccessor, field) { fields.push(kendo.isPresent(index) ? index : (indexAccessor || field)); return undefined$1; }); return fields; },
    
    getter: function(expression, safe) { var key = expression + safe; return getterCache[key] = getterCache[key] || (function (obj) { var fields = kendo.exprToArray(expression, safe); var result = obj; for (var idx = 0; idx < fields.length; idx++) { result = result[fields[idx]]; if (!kendo.isPresent(result) && safe) { return result; } } return result; }); },
```